# Help with $\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{x}^{\pi}\frac{\sin y}{y}\,dy\,dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

For one of my Calculus 3 practice problems we are given 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{x}^{\pi}\frac{\sin y}{y}\,dy\,dx$$

I am having difficulty trying to integrate in terms of $y$, should I switch the order of integration from $dy\,dx$ to $dx\,dy$? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You absolutely should.

Comment: Yes...................

Comment: @DougM would it also work if I split this function up? Or is changing the order of integration the easiest way to go about it. Thanks

Comment: Change the order of integration and the problem is a snap.  $\int \frac {sin y}{y} dy$ is not integrable into elementary functions.  Unless you are comfortable with exotic functions you must find a way to turn that into something integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^\pi\int_x^\pi \frac{\sin y}{y}dydx=\int_0^\pi\int_0^y \frac{\sin y}{y}dxdy$$
$$=\int_0^\pi \left(\int_0^y dx\right)\frac{\sin y}{y}dy$$
$$=\int_0^\pi y\frac{\sin y}{y}dy$$
$$=\int_0^\pi \sin y dy$$
$$=\left[-\cos y\right]_0^\pi$$
$$=2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\pi\int_x^\pi \frac{\sin y}{y}dydx=\int_0^\pi\int_0^y \frac{\sin y}{y}dxdy = \int_0^\pi \sin y~dy = 2$$